# Export excel values into playing card template

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have very limited experience with photoshop (only use it for sketching/coloring). I am currently creating a word-based board game and have an excel sheet with 500 or so words.

Is there an easy way I can batch these words onto a playing card template in photoshop? Or would I have to copy and paste each word from the list onto the template by hand?

Comment: If the words are not being "decorated" in any way, you might consider setting up a carefully constructed mail merge, and also a single-page card template in photoshop without the words. You can then use the image as a **watermark** set to "100% image size; 100% opacity, behind page content" either in word or by "printing to PDF" and setting the watermark via the pdf software.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows and have MS Office, there are a couple of add-ins out there that would merge the Excel data onto a series of PowerPoint slides, one slide per word, in a few seconds.

You could then save the slides out as images (PNG, JPG, etc) from PowerPoint.

If you whisper stuff like merge excel powerpoint to google, it'll lead you to these add-ins.  Disclaimer: one of them is mine (PPTools PPTMerge).  If this is a one-shot job, ping me from the Contact link on each page at pptools.com; you can probably talk me into doing the merge for you and sending back a merged PPT file if you supply the XL and original PowerPoint files.